# Some confusion about nohup

Tags: bash, nohup

**Situation1**

command

1. `find / -name "*.conf"`
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to pause the process

**Situation2**

--- hello.sh ---

> #!/bin/bash
>      /bin/sleep 5000

command
`./hello.sh &`

**Situation3**

command
`nohup ./hello.sh &`

**finally**
command

`pstree | less` to get the processes info

> ```
> |-sshd-+-sshd
> |      |-sshd---bash
> |      `-sshd---bash-+-find
> |                    |-2*[hello.sh---sleep]
> |                    |-less
> |                    `-pstree
> ```

then I exit the `ssh`

I get the pstree info in another `ssh`

> ```
> init-|      
>      |-2*[hello.sh---sleep]
> ```

**question**

1. Why do I run `hello.sh` and use `nohup` to suspend `hello.sh`, the result will be the same?
2. Why does the `find` process not appear like the `hello.sh` process? When parent process was killed , `init` process will possess the orphan process.
3. Is it necessary to use `nohup` if I want background a process?

Comment: In situation 2, if im not mistaken, if process needs to read from stdin  , it will be stopped. Once shell closes, its background process will be closed too. Nohup allows exiting shell and keeping program running.

Comment: I think `find` needs to write to stdout. That's the key to explain the cases. And, I think needing to read from stdin may be another factor, though it's not in the above cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question, but I'll try to explain the use of `nohup`:

From the manual page `man nohup`:

> nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty

So `nohup` disconnects the standard input and output streams from the terminal (`/dev/null` becomes input, output goes to file `nohup.out`) and also shields the application from `SIGHUP` signals (hangup signal). This allows you to terminate the shell process from which you started the `nohup`-ed command without killing this child process.

---

A similar way to prevent killing of a process when the parent shell gets terminated is `disown`:

```
my_command & disown
```

This runs `my_command` in background and disowns it from the parent process, but without performing any I/O redirection. It effectively makes the command an independent process, no longer being a child process of the parent shell.

---

When you only want to run a process in background, but don't want to disown it from the current shell (so that it will be killed when the parent process exits), you can omit the `nohup` or `disown` and only use Bash's `&` :

```
my_command &
```